# How to create a table with filters for my plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and I need to create a page for products/plans and I need to create that page with a table, filters and a top button "Add New", how can I do that?

This page for products/plans should be a custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two standard way of creating admin listing table in wordpress.

1. Using [**register_post_type**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)
2. Extend **WP_List_Table** class by copying it in our plugin because it's a core class that can be modified by WordPress, It's located inside (/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php) directory.